# Select query fetch first row only

Tags: php, mysql

The $pKeyArray only prints first row from the database which meets the WHERE clause, why isn't showing all rows which meets the WHERE clause, I don't want to put it in any loop, i just need is an array of P_Key of all rows.

```
$getPKey = "SELECT P_Key FROM likersTable WHERE executed=0";
$PKeyDetails = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$getPKey)
                or die('Some error in post id');
$pKeyArray = mysqli_fetch_array($PKeyDetails);
print_r($pKeyArray);
```

Comment: Are you sure there is more than one result for that query? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `mysqli_fetch_array()` for each row.

```
while ($pKeyArray = mysqli_fetch_array($PKeyDetails)) {
    print_r($pKeyArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysqli_fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_all):

```
$array = mysqli_fetch_all( $PKeyDetails);
```

Comment: You need PHP >= 5.3 and need to be using the MySQL Native Driver.

Comment: any other way out? actually by this i will get an array which i want to further user WHERE IN clause, if you can help me with one single query for that

Comment: i am doing this after the above sql $ids = join(',',$pKeyArray); 
$updateFlag = "UPDATE likersTable SET executed=1 WHERE P_KEY IN ($ids)";
   $updateFlagDone = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$updateFlag)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a loop because the `mysqli_fetch_*()` functions only returns one row per call.

Use this code:

```
$getPKey = "SELECT P_Key FROM likersTable WHERE executed=0";
$PKeyDetails = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$getPKey)
                or die('Some error in post id');

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($PKeyDetails))
{
  // Do something with $row
}
```

Or use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_all):

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($PKeyDetails, MYSQLI_ASSOC); // or use MYSQLI_NUM
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_all() giving an error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()

Comment: any other way out? actually by this i will get an array which i want to further user WHERE IN clause, if you can help me with one single query for that

Comment: i am doing this after the above sql $ids = join(',',$pKeyArray); $updateFlag = "UPDATE likersTable SET executed=1 WHERE P_KEY IN ($ids)"; $updateFlagDone = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$updateFlag)

Comment: I am not a SQL pro but couldn't you just write `UPDATE likersTable SET executed=1 WHERE P_KEY IN (SELECT P_KEY FROM likersTable WHERE executed=0)`? By the way why don't you want to use loops?

Comment: i got it working, i stored $row in an array with while loop, then used it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11039/discussion-between-pal-singh-and-comfreek)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($pKeyArray = mysqli_fetch_array($PKeyDetails)) {
    print_r($pKeyArray);
}
```